# Transaction Control language in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a one procedure in that i need to implement tcl for avoiding unwanted updates in table.
I tried to return value 1 if the condition is match else i will return 0 if the condition will not match but i could not able to return 1 even if the condition is satisfy

**Procedure**

```
 begin
    if(value1= value2)

    begin transaction
    ------
    ------
    ------
    Commit Transaction
    Return
    set @result=1
    select @result
    End

    Else
    begin
    set @result=0
    select @result
    end
    End
```

> This procedure will return only @result=0.

**Updated:**

```
Create procedure [dbo].[oc_AofA_Update_WO7965&WO7951_test] 
     @aoa_DateStamped smalldatetime = null,                                                              
     @aoa_DateSent smalldatetime = null,                                                              
     @aoa_Scanned bit = null,
     @accval_LastUpdatetime varchar(100) = null,
     @accval_LastUpdateError int output               
as  
set nocount on  
    declare @Retrivedate varchar(100)
    declare @NewRetrivedate varchar(100)                                                              
BEGIN
If(@accval_LastUpdatetime=@NewRetrivedate)
Begin                                                 

BEGIN TRANSACTION                                                              
 CREATE TABLE #tmp(remarks  ntext)                                                              
 INSERT INTO #tmp(remarks) SELECT  aoa_Remarks   FROM TBL_APPOINTMENTOFAGENT WHERE aoa_AccountID = @aoa_AccountID                                                              

             DECLARE @maxlength_oldval  int                            
             DECLARE @maxlength_newval  int                               
 SET @maxlength_oldval = (SELECT DATALENGTH(remarks) FROM #tmp)
   if cast(@aoa_DateStamped as varchar) = '' 
   BEGIN
        IF @@ERROR !=0                                                              
                BEGIN                                                              
                 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION                                                              
                 RETURN                                                       
                END                                                                  

               set @accval_LastUpdateError=1
               select @accval_LastUpdateError as accval_LastUpdateError1                                                             
   END  

   ELSE 
      UPDATE TBL_CLIENTS                                                                
              SET                          
              client_AuthorizationCode=@accval_LastUpdateError          
             WHERE client_ClientID=@aoa_Scanned                
                IF @@ERROR !=0                                        
                BEGIN                                                    
                 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION                                                              
                 RETURN      
                END
                COMMIT TRANSACTION                                                             
                    RETURN                                                            

    END 
                set @accval_LastUpdateError=1
                select @accval_LastUpdateError as accval_LastUpdateError1                                                         
End  



END
```

Comment: You are not `return`ing anything

Comment: Actually that @return parameter is output parameter. I just set the value 1 if value1 and value2 is equal.

Comment: Can you show the actual procedure, what you have posted won't parse at all.

Comment: I had update my actual procedure

Comment: Now, referencing your actual code, what unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

In various place inside your store procedure you have the line `RETURN`. This causes the procedure to immediately return to the calling party. In other words it doesn't continue and never sets your `@accval_LastUpdateError` variable to anything.

The procedure is quite messy, the below code is likely what you are looking for.

But I would make some very quick suggestions first:

1. Be consistent in your style. For example, you have `Begin` and `BEGIN`. Try to stick with one of them.
2. Be consistent with your indentation. For example, after a `BEGIN`, (not a `BEGIN TRAN` as that's not a control flow statement) indent once.
3. You don't need to use an `OUTPUT` parameter, you could use the procedure return value (i.e. `RETURN 1`.

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[oc_AofA_Update_WO7965&WO7951_test] 
     @aoa_DateStamped SMALLDATETIME = null,                                                              
     @aoa_DateSent SMALLDATETIME = null,                                                              
     @aoa_Scanned BIT = null,
     @accval_LastUpdatetime VARCHAR(100) = null,
     @accval_LastUpdateError INT OUTPUT               
AS  

SET NOCOUNT ON  
DECLARE @Retrivedate VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @NewRetrivedate VARCHAR(100)                                                              

BEGIN
    IF(@accval_LastUpdatetime=@NewRetrivedate)
    BEGIN                                                 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION                                                              
    IF CAST(@aoa_DateStamped AS VARCHAR) = '' 
    BEGIN
        IF @@ERROR !=0                                                              
        BEGIN                                                              
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION                                                              
            --RETURN                                                       
        END                                                                  

        SET @accval_LastUpdateError=1
        SELECT @accval_LastUpdateError AS accval_LastUpdateError1  

    END
    ELSE
    IF @@ERROR !=0                                        
    BEGIN                                                    
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION                                                              
        --RETURN      
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION                                                             
    --RETURN                                                            

    END 

    SET @accval_LastUpdateError=1
    SELECT @accval_LastUpdateError AS accval_LastUpdateError1                                                         

END
```

Comment: Thanks David its working now... Also i used Tcl first time that is why little confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put BEGIN..END around your first code block, starting a transaction does not implicitly do this.

```
 begin
    if(value1= value2)
    BEGIN
    begin transaction
    ------
    ------
    ------
    Commit Transaction
    Return
    set @result=1
    select @result
    End transaction
    END
    Else
    begin
    set @result=0
    select @result
    end
  End
```

Comment: I had put Begin and End but i could not able to get the @result =1 Tab Allem

Comment: Looking at your actual code, you are missing a "BEGIN" after "ELSE"